# Linear model with factor variables

Tags: r, categorical-data, linear-model

I am analyzing some data containing numeric and factor variables in R, factor variables have two levels.
To my surprise, there is interaction between one numeric and one factor variable on both levels of the factor variable in summary of linear model

```
lm.default(formula = blue ~ Anum + Anum:as.factor(D) + Bnum:as.factor(F) + 
as.factor(D) + as.factor(F), data = design_center)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-13.7655  -3.7701  -0.5086   3.9567  16.5527 

Coefficients:
                    Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)         135.1981     6.6764  20.250   <2e-16 ***
Anum                 -0.2499     1.8921  -0.132   0.8957    
as.factor(D)1        14.9358     8.3769   1.783   0.0838 .  
as.factor(F)1        70.7848     4.6733  15.147   <2e-16 ***
Anum:as.factor(D)1   -6.0673     2.6759  -2.267   0.0300 *  
Bnum:as.factor(F)-1   1.9776     0.9461   2.090   0.0444 *  
Bnum:as.factor(F)1   -1.8972     0.9461  -2.005   0.0532 .  
---
```

where

```
as.factor(design_center$F)
 [1] -1 1  1  -1 1  -1 -1 1  1  -1 -1 1  -1 1  1  -1 1  -1 -1 1  -1 1  1  -1 -1 1  1  -1 1  -1 -1 1  -1 1  -1 1  -1 1  -1 1 
Levels: -1 1
```

and

```
typeof(Bnum) 
[1] "double"
```

I thought, that all the lower values of the binary factor variables are contained in the intercept, so what is with the weird interaction between F and Bnum?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Try re-running including Bnum as a main effect and see what happens.

Comment: ah, I see, thanks a lot :)